# Java, using throw without try block

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, throw

For the following method, is it okay to throw the exception when it isn't inside a 'try' block?

```
public void setCapacity(x) throws CapacityExceededException {
    if (x > 10) throw new CapacityExceededException(x);
    else this.x = x;
}
```

Comment: `throw`ing and `catch`ing (or `try`ing to `catch`) are different things

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is Ok to throw an exception when it isn't inside a try block. All you have do is declare that your method throws an exception. Otherwise compiler will give an error.

```
public void setCapacity(x) throws CapacityExceededException {
    if (x > 10) throw new CapacityExceededException(x);
    else this.x = x;
}
```

You don't even have to do that if your `CapacityExceededException` extends Runtime Exception.

```
public void setA(int a) {
            this.a = a;
            if(a<0) throw new NullPointerException();
        }
```

This code won't give any compiler error. As NPE is a RuntimeException.

When you throw an exception the exception will be propagated to the method which called `setCapacity()` method. That method has to deal with the exception via try catch or propagate it further up the call stack by rethrowing it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is ok. You simply need to add throws clause for method in case it throws a checked exception. There is no restriction of a try clause for throwing an exception. For example if you have a stack and called `pop()` method and size is zero you can check it and throw an exception. You may need to catch the exception wherever you plan to invoke this method. Otherwise this uncaught exception will move up the invocation stack and will be finally handled by JVM and it will print stack trace on `System.err` stream. We can also specify our own handler if we want:

```
public class CustomUncaughtExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
  public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
     // Write the custom logic here
   }
}
```

You do not even need to mention exception in throws if it is a `RunTimException`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `throws` declaration:

```
public int getCapacity() throws CapacityExceededException {
    // Something goes here
}
```

Otherwise, you'll get compiler warnings. This will get the method to throw the exception. However, whenever you execute the method, you will have to use the `try` block. This is because an exception could be thrown by execution of the method.

```
try {
    getCapacity()
} catch (CapacityExceededException e) {
    // Do Something
}
```

Comment: You get compiler **errors** only for exceptions which don't inherit from `RuntimeException`

Comment: So then you don't need the `throws` declaration in the method, you can just throw it (I'm also very new to java, so feel free to make edits if something is wrong)

Answer (score 0):

> ... is it okay to throw the exception when it isn't inside a 'try' block?

Of course<sup>1</sup> it is!.

Indeed ... that is the most common way to throw exceptions.

Indeed 2 ... if we didn't use exceptions like that, they would be (almost) redundant since we could (almost) replace them with "break to label" and a local variable to hold the exception information.

---

<sup>1 - Provided that the exception is unchecked<sup>2</sup>, or you declared it in the method signature.</sup>

<sup>2 - That is `RuntimeException`, `Error` or descendants of the same.</sup>